According to Catholicism, would a person who had a vasectomy but never had sex afterwards be committing sin?
While I’m aware that the Catholic Church teaches that having sex after a vasectomy (or getting your tubes tied for women) is sinful because it is an act of contraception, I was wondering if the church taught that the act of vasectomy itself was sinful. Would a person who got one be sinning even if he never had sex for the rest of his life?

Why would someone want to do that ? Sin is a matter of intention not of inadvertent outcome. The question lacks essential detail.

I think this question can be understood as "Is a vasectomy a sin only because of the intention of contraceptive sex or is it sinful per se (in itself)?"

"having sex after a vasectomy (or getting your tubes tied for women) is sinful because it is an act of contraception" Not necessarily. An infertile husband or wife rendering the marital debt doesn't sin.

@Geremia since the act of vasectomy (broadly speaking) is an act ordered towards contraception, it is categorically different than being infertile unintentionally. That shouldn't be a hard thing to grasp.

@LukeHill Even if a husband or wife makes himself or herself infertile by bodily mutilation, subsequent renderings of the marital act would not by that fact be sinful (exacting the marriage debt would be formal cooperation in contraception, however; cf. 2nd ¶ here). Perhaps the positive restatement of your question is: "Can an intentionally infertile husband or wife exact the marriage debt without sinning?"?

There are situations when a vasectomy or prostatectomy is morally permissible.
Ethical and Religious Directives for Catholic Hospitals (1954), directive 31 (Kelly, S.J., Medico-Moral Problems pp. 183-4):

Procedures that induce sterility, whether permanent or temporary, are permitted when:
a) they are immediately directed to the cure, diminution, or prevention of a serious pathological condition;
b) a simpler treatment is not reasonably available; and
c) the sterility itself is an unintended and, in the circumstances, an unavoidable effect.


This is a good distinction to include, which is less obvious from the question text. It would be good to clarify the morality of vasectomy absent medical justification without intended sexual acts.

@eques That's already clear, and is in the premise of the question. Where sterility is the intended result, it's not permissible. It doesn't matter if the man makes "use" of that sterility or not -- in fact that's completely irrelevant.

@AndrewLeach " is in the premise of the question." The OP asks that specifically, hence it would be useful to state that the intention of sterilization even if one (for some reason) intended not to actually pursue an act which would now be sterile would still be sinful.
